# Attach and configure ms sql server database using installation package

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, installshield

i have some Db steps (attach database, adding and configure a  new login, configure roles) and i want to automize it using installation package. Right now in project we are using standard Visual studio installer. Can i implement  db steps using standard visual studio intaller (custom actions or something else)? Or maybe i should use some others installers like Install shield, Wix?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Visual Studio setup project doesn't offer this functionality out of the box (although, my experience with it is tiny). Also, it is not a good idea to implement it all from scratch in a custom action - it is really the last resort.

Other vendors, at least those you mentioned, do offer this. if you decide to move to one of those, keep in mind the learning curve, which will take some of your time (for WiX is probably more). However, if the VS setup project is quite small and simple, it might be a good idea to move at this point, considering the fact that [VS setup project type was deprecated by Microsoft](http://blogs.msmvps.com/installsite/blog/2012/04/05/visual-studio-installer-projects-no-longer-supported-in-visual-studio-11-replaced-by-installshield-le/).

Answer (score 0):

For DB configuration you may create SQL script which can be installed with an application or into temp directory and feed it to whatever consumes sql scripts in mssql (in oracle its sqlplus). Not sure about visual studio but that's how I saw in one project for InstallShield.